# Porque no carga mi video en html

Tags: html

estoy intentando poner un video en una pagina html pero no carga, se queda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo esta asi:

```
  <video src="img/HumanFinal.mp4" source="video/mp4" controls>
```

Es solo eso, el video esta bien puesto, no se porque sucede la verdad, me gustaria solucionarlo, gracias de antemanto

Comment: Has verificado el video?. Porque si me resulta funcional

Comment: Si, el vídeo funciona

Comment: En el atributo `source` tienes mal definida la ruta del video, debería quedar algo así: `source="video.mp4"` si el video está en la misma carpeta donde está tu código `html`, en caso contrario, debes poner la ruta completa de tu video, con el nombre exacto del video. Por ejemplo `source="videos/naturaleza.mp4`. [Aquí te dejo un recurso](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) para que uses adecuadamente el tag video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

source no es un atributo de la etiqueta video, es otra etiqueta hija donde se define el src que es el atributo de ruta donde se encuentra el archivo, también te falto agregar el atributo type

```
 <video controls>
  <source src="img/HumanFinal.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```

Esto debería funcionar.